# Angular Lazy Loading from a folder outside the app folder

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Using the following directory folder structure and code:

I'm trying to Lazy Load this module

```
"tsdmns-modules/loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module.module"
```

from

```
"app/app-routing.module"
```

and then load this component

```
"/tsdmns-modules/loader-module/views/tsdmns-loader-view-console.component"
```

from

```
"tsdmns-modules/loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module-routing.module"
```

As I go to `"http://localhost:4200/loader"` it goes back to root

I guess I have an issue with

```
  {
    path: 'loader',
    loadChildren: 'src/tsdmns-modules/loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module.module#TsdmnsLoaderModuleModule'
  }
```

Am I writing this folder directory correctly?

```
"src/tsdmns-modules/loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module.module"
```

---

```
app/
-- app.module
-- app-routing.module

tsdmns-modules/
-- loader-module/
-- -- tsdmns-loader-module.module
-- -- tsdmns-loader-module-routing.module
-- -- views/
-- -- -- tsdmns-loader-view-console.component
```

---

```
[AppModule]
-----------
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestpageComponent } from './testpage/testpage.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestpageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

-------------------------------------------------------------

[AppRoutingModule]
------------------
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TestpageComponent } from './testpage/testpage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: TestpageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'loader',
    loadChildren: 'src/tsdmns-modules/loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module.module#TsdmnsLoaderModuleModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

-------------------------------------------------------------

[TsdmnsLoaderModuleModule]
--------------------------
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { TsdmnsLoaderModuleRoutingModule } from './tsdmns-loader-module-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TsdmnsLoaderModuleRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class TsdmnsLoaderModuleModule { }

-------------------------------------------------------------

[TsdmnsLoaderModuleRoutingModule]
---------------------------------
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TsdmnsLoaderViewConsoleComponent } from '../views/tsdmns-loader-view-console/tsdmns-loader-view-console.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TsdmnsLoaderViewConsoleComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TsdmnsLoaderModuleRoutingModule { }
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far you have done everything right except for the router module path and the component declaration in the lazy loaded module. Your `loadChildren` path should be relative to your `app-routing.module`'s current location. According to your folder structure it should be

```
// In your app-routing.module
{
  path: 'loader',
  loadChildren: '../tsdmns-modules/loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module.module#TsdmnsLoaderModuleModule'
}
```

And also you have to declare your `TsdmnsLoaderViewConsoleComponent` component in your module as well

```
// In your tsdmns-loader-module.module
@NgModule({
 declarations: [TsdmnsLoaderViewConsoleComponent],
 imports: [
   CommonModule,
   TsdmnsLoaderModuleRoutingModule
 ]
})
export class TsdmnsLoaderModuleModule { }
```

I have prepared a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmc5bt?file=src%2Ftsdmns-modules%2Ftsdmns-loader-routing.module.ts) for your code. FYI keep in mind the [Angular style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#naming) when naming your files and components.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I originally had

loadChildren: '../tsdmns-modules/loader-module/tsdmns-loader-module.module#TsdmnsLoaderModuleModule'

but changed it. But thanks to you I realized my issue from the beginning was I didn't declare "TsdmnsLoaderViewConsoleComponent" in "tsdmns-loader-module.module"